# Unicode character escape sequences instead of text upon mouse-2 paste from other windows

Tags: copy-paste, mouse, unicode, x11

I am having a weird problem with emacs:

When pasting non-ascii text, e.g. `€` from X-clipboard with the middle mouse button into x-enabled emacs I get Unicode character escape sequences, e.g. `\u20ac` instead of `€`.

If, however, I first do a "Copy" in the other window and then do `C-y` in emacs window, the text is inserted verbatim.

How can this be fixed?

Note: this behavior is not observed when pasting with the middle mouse button into emacs running inside xterm, that is in xterm pasting is fine both ways, with mouse and with `C-y`.

Comment: Does the following help? `(setq x-select-request-type '(UTF8_STRING COMPOUND_TEXT TEXT STRING))`